# Using uncertainty accuracy

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Lets say I have 2 lists, containing elements:

1. values
2. uncertainties of the values

Values are stored as exact fractions and I want to print out combined list of numerical values. For example if i have 1 element lists:

```
ExA = {5251/977, 19087/53};
ExB = {53/19087, 977/5251};
```

I want the output to be: `{5.3746 ± 0.0028, 360.13 ± 0.19}`, with using `Err[ExA, ExB]`.

Basically I want uncertainty to have a element precision of 2 digits and value to have same precision as the paired uncertainty. At the moment I have:

```
Err[x_, \[CapitalDelta]x_]:=
  N[x] \[PlusMinus] NumberForm[N[\[CapitalDelta]x], 2];
SetAttributes[Err, Listable];
```

Edit:
Following almost works as I want:

```
Err[x_, \[CapitalDelta]x_] := 
 PlusMinus[
  NumberForm[N[x], {10, 2 - MantissaExponent[\[CapitalDelta]x][[2]]}],
   NumberForm[N[\[CapitalDelta]x], 2]]
SetAttributes[Err, Listable];
```

If uncertainties second digit rounds to 0, then shorter version is used - I do not want that. For example `1.7007 ± 0.006` where I want `1.7007 ± 0.0060`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard : Well, if written in scientific notation, I want the value to have same multiplier and number of decimal places, as uncertainty does.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard : It does not work, if `Err` is used inside a list.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard : I mean `{Err[m, \[CapitalDelta]m], Err[t, \[CapitalDelta]t]}`, does not work for example.

Comment: Margus, I made yet another edit.  Hopefully I have my head on straight this time.

Comment: It seems I missed your update.  Back to the drawing board! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Improved version, inspired by Daniel's answer:

```
SetAttributes[Err, Listable]

Err[n_, e_] := N[n, {∞, 2 - Log10@e}] ± N[e, 2]
```

---

Testing

```
ExA = {5251/977, 19087/53, 850341/500000};
ExB = {53/19087, 977/5251, 151/25000};

Err[ExA, ExB]

Err[5251/977, 53/19087]
```

```
{5.3746 ± 0.0028, 360.13 ± 0.19, 1.7007 ± 0.0060}

5.3746 ± 0.0028
```

Comment: Margus, thanks for the accept.  Please see the improved version I just added.

Answer (score 7):

Corrected version:

Can use N[...,2] on the errors, then take N[...,{Infinity,Accuracy[error]}] on the central values. THis second numericization causes the accuracy of each central value to match the accuracy of its corresponding error.

```
PlusMinus @@@ 
  Map[{N[#[[1]], {Infinity, Accuracy[#[[2]]]}], #[[2]]} &, 
   Transpose[{ExA, N[ExB, 2]}]]
```

Out[113]= {5.3746 [PlusMinus] 0.0028, 360.13 [PlusMinus] 0.19}

Daniel Lichtblau